# Put else statement that is inside a while loop into one div

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a while loop and inside the while loop there is an if-else statement. All I want to do is put all the contents of the else statements into one div. It's in Wordpress.

I can't seem to get the logic behind it..

```
<?php /* The loop */ 
        $i = 1;
        ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php 
                static $count = 0;
                if ($count == 5) { break; }
                else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="content_container">
                    <?php
                        if($i == 1) {
                            ?><span style="width:370px;" class="main active"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></span><?php
                        } else {
                            ?><span class="child nonactive"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></span><?php
                        }
                        $i++;
                        $count++;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                } 
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="content_container">
<span <?php if($i == 1) { ?> style="width:370px;" class="main active" <?php } else {?> class="child nonactive" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></span>
<?php  }
$i++;
$count++;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is does not do it. I only want the else statements to be put inside ONE div.

Comment: see properly, its one div

Comment: cant understand, please explain

Comment: I don't want to include the statements inside the IF. I only want the statements inside the ELSE. In addition, I want the statements inside the ELSE inside ONE div.

Comment: what you want ? the structure or output. plz clarify